# How to remove "SOAPAction" HTTP header from Savon request

Tags: ruby, http, header, savon

How would I remove the HTTP headers from a Savon request for example

```
client.request 'v5:ProcessShipments' do
  client.http.headers["SOAPAction"] = "example_post"
end
```

This would generate

```
DEBUG -- : SOAPAction: example_post
```

And the server would respond

```
Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: example_post.
```

However I dont want to have any SOAPAction(s)

I have tried to clear the variable and delete it. I search for a while and couldn't find anything so I hope this hasn't been asked before.

Thanks in advance.

If I dont override it then by default Savon will use the client.request 'v5:ProcessShipments', which is also incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quote from [savon documentation](http://fagiani.github.com/savon/) for the future references:

> SOAPAction is an HTTP header information required by legacy services.
>   If present, the header value must have double quotes surrounding the
>   URI-reference (SOAP 1.1. spec, section 6.1.1).

By reading savon source code I figured out that Savon::Client#request method sets "SOAPAction" header automatically before it yields a block. I tried to delete SOAPAction header and it worked:

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = "test.wsdl"
end

client.request :wsdl, "sayHello" do
    http.headers.delete("SOAPAction")
end
```

Here is the request it generates:

```
SOAP request: http://www.examples.com/SayHello/
DEBUG -- : Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 332
DEBUG -- : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xmlns:wsdl="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
                            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <wsdl:sayHello></wsdl:sayHello>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

As you can see there is no SOAPAction HTTP header.

HTH

Comment: Hi Alex, thats great and thanks very much for going into details on how you actually debugged this as well.